# Overcome locked screen + silent mode to play audio

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, notifications

[This video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqbgtmrhpa4jwgr/VIDEO%20DEMONSTRATION.MOV) is a recording of an app which can

- over-ride silent mode
- over-ride locked screen
- play alarm music/melody

Our team is working on a similar custom iphone alarm clock

I would be so grateful if someone could help. I have been trying to break this for two weeks.

our below method is not called when device is locked. that's why alarm sound is not playing

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    
    if ([GlobalData gSettings].vibration) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        isVibration = YES;
    } else {
        isVibration = NO;
    }
    
    self.uinfo = notification.userInfo;
    
    
    
    NSString *soundname = [uinfo objectForKey:@"sound"];
    NSURL *clip = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:soundname withExtension:@"caf"];
    if (clip) {
        
        self.avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:clip error:NULL];
        self.avPlayer.delegate = self;
        AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        AudioSessionSetActive(true);
        
        // Allow playback even if Ring/Silent switch is on mute
        UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                                 sizeof(sessionCategory),&sessionCategory);
    }
    else
    {
        
        NSURL *clip = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]URLForKey:[uinfo objectForKey:@"sound"]];
        self.avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:clip error:NULL];
        self.avPlayer.delegate = self;
        AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        AudioSessionSetActive(true);
        
        // Allow playback even if Ring/Silent switch is on mute
        UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                                 sizeof(sessionCategory),&sessionCategory);
    }
    

    [self.avPlayer play];
```

Comment: "I would be so grateful if someone could help." With what? What's your question?

Comment: please see above additions

Comment: have you checked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14641433/843366 ? The `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` override the silent mode for me, the other part of the answer should help you with lock screen

Comment: we have implemented this but with iOS 6.1.3 the sound does not play. the volume control appears to increase but there the audio does not appear until the iphone is unlocked?

Comment: i would be willing to pay 50 dollar bounty if someone can help us find a solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

I dug into the LivingEarth app a little. It seems they are using [MMDeepSleepPreventer](https://github.com/marcop/MMPDeepSleepPreventer) based -component. And they use some sort of internal alarms system(music being played is NOT triggered by the local notification but probably by `NSTimer`).

However, I found it to not be reliable in newer iOS versions, so I tweaked it a little. When launched it keeps playing the silent audio file which makes possible for app to run the `NSTimers` even if user pressed the lock button.

You can find my fork [here](https://github.com/mzygar/MMPDeepSleepPreventer).