# IOS: Run application audio and phone music audio together in background

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudiosession

I need my application audio to still run even though it goes into the background with device music audio. I try the codes suggestion in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725192/how-do-i-start-playing-audio-when-in-silent-mode-locked-in-ios-6) but my application still doesn't work.

[image]

1. Set Required background mode to App plays audio
2. Set Application does not run in background to YES

AppDelegate.m

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

Comment: Have you set the specific permission in the info.plist?

Comment: I already have set it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a related question about it.

[How to handle background audio playing while iOS device is locked or on another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429204/how-to-handle-background-audio-playing-while-ios-device-is-locked-or-on-another)

I would suggest you to take a look a this tutorial:

[http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/)

It explains all the **different steps to follow**.