# Private API to always keep app open

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

Hi I am looking for a way to make sure that my app cannot be completely closed or at least automatically open when the iPhone turns on.  I am happy to use any private api's to accomplish this.  Is this possible?  Although it may affect battery life, for the b2b app i am making it needs to always listen for certain events and we do not want the user closing it out.  Thank you for any help in this!

Comment: If you can't accomplish what you want with the documented API's, you're probably either doing it wrong and/or not supposed to do it. What are these "certain events" you're trying to listen for??

Comment: well im pretty sure that you cannot accomplish this with documented API's since its without user control.  I am listening for an iBeacon device but if the app is closed it wont connect to the device.  It only works if the app is open and I want to make sure the user cannot close it.

Comment: Is the device bluetooth connected? I think you can register an app to respond to certain types of things connecting to your device

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

**Restarting an app**

VOIP application automatically start applications after reboot and in couple of other cases. So, it's better to use it.

**Continuously running**

There are couple of methods.

Most commons are:

1) Play silent audio in the loop:

Look at these

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios
- [How do I start playing audio when in silent mode & locked in iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725192/how-do-i-start-playing-audio-when-in-silent-mode-locked-in-ios-6)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/brighton-iphone-creators/CT6HByrUT3c

2) Use turning on and off LocationManager

**Prevent app from being closed**

I am not aware of this one.

Answer (score 0):

No need for private APIs if you physically control the device in question: use **guided access mode**.